# Tomcat, database and serial communication

Tags: java

I’m looking for the best approach for developing application which will read data from serial port (rxtx) and store readouts in database. The app will have web interface.

The question is if  Tomact + Servlets/jsp is correct approach.

I’m in doubt if Tomcat should/can manage serial communication?

Regards

Comment: Voting to close as this question is not a good candidate for SO - answering your question: java can deal with serial ports. Is it the correct approach? maybe... too many unknowns to answer.

Comment: If Java can handle rs232 Tomcat can too